# Max retries exceeded with url: / Caused by ProxyError

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

i wanted to get some proxy list from this webPage; https://free-proxy-list.net/
but i stuck in this error and dont know how to fix it.

```
requests.exceptions.ProxyError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='free-proxy-list.net', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x00000278BFFA1EB0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected 
party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond')))
```

and btw, this is my related code:

```
import urllib
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
ua = UserAgent(cache=False)
header = {
    "User-Agent": str(ua.msie)
    }
proxy = {
    "https": "http://95.66.151.101:8080"
}
urls = "https://free-proxy-list.net/"
res = requests.get(urls, proxies=proxy)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,'lxml')
```

and i tried to **scrape** other web sites, but i realized that its not the way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your using https in the Json dict when your proxy is a http proxy

Proxies should always be inside this format

**For a http proxy**

```
{'"http": "Http Proxy"}
```

**For a https proxy**

```
{"https":"Https Proxy"}
```

And for the UserAgent

```
{"User-Agent": "Opera/9.80 (X11; Linux x86_64; U; de) Presto/2.2.15 Version/10.00"}
```

**Example**

```py
import requests
requests.get("https://example.com", proxies={"http":"http://95.66.151.101:8080"}, headers={"User-Agent": "Opera/9.80 (X11; Linux x86_64; U; de) Presto/2.2.15 Version/10.00"})
```

The module `from fake_useragent import UserAgent` You imported is irrelevant and unnecessary

**Extra**

The error could've also happened because the proxy isn't valid or responded improperly

If you are looking for free lists of proxies consider checking out these sources

https://pastebin.com/raw/VJwVkqRT

https://proxyscrape.com/free-proxy-list

https://www.freeproxylists.net/

Comment: It really works!! I used to believe that when configuring proxies, 'http' and 'https' represent different protocol of the website you are visiting. Thanks again!

Answer (score -1):

I have never seen the `fake_useragent` module and don't know what its for, but I removed it. Also don't know why you added these header elements, but I dont believe it is necessary for the task you described. Looking at the html in your link, the proxies are in `section id="list"-->div class="container"--> <tbody>`. The below code does give all the elements in the mentioned area, and includes all the proxies. You can alter this if you want to get more specific info.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

urls = "https://free-proxy-list.net/"
res = requests.get(urls)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"html.parser")


tbody = soup.find("tbody")

print(tbody.prettify())
```

Comment: the exact same error? This is working for me so that is very weird

Comment: Have you configured a proxy that is unreachable?

Comment: nah . i didnt do anything . i think its about my ip address, do u know something about it ?

Comment: Your code wouldn't run even with correct proxy. The code I posted should work. My code not working indicates you have configured your proxies wrong (`ProxyError`). I have no information about your setup so I cant help you further. I doubt its about your IP though.

Comment: i found what's the problem, this website (https://free-proxy-list.net/) is filter in our country (Iran), and the proxy i've set ```proxy = {
    "https": "http://95.66.151.101:8080"
}``` did not work as well , so i have to find another proxy :D , thanks for your time mate.

Comment: btw , UserAgent is for fake ID of any Browser like IE, Chrome,FireFox etc. it's a way for scraping (Fake_useragent)it's a nice tool.